# How to filter and select multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I can't select and filter multiple columns together in Pandas. `'Name'` and `'Year of Rank'` are column names. Thank you!

```
dw[dw.Name=='El Toro' & dw['Name', 'Year of Rank']]
```

Comment: This is literally the first thing you learn when reading about [pandas selecting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) . Try the docs in the beginning, it's likely that will be very helpful

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you want:

```
dw[dw['Name'] == 'El Toro'][['Name','Year of Rank']]
```

or alternatively:

```
dw.loc[ dw['Name'] == 'El Toro', ['Name','Year of Rank']]
```

**Edit:**
As pointed out in the comments, the second one is much preferred as it deals with the filtering and selection as a single entity.

Comment: the first one isn't [recommended](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

Comment: Awesome, yes, it worked but still do not understand how it works.

Comment: Indeed @AlperAtakan, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

dw = pd.DataFrame([
  {'Name': 'A', 'Year of Rank':1992, 'Rank': 1},
  {'Name': 'El Toro', 'Year of Rank':1993, 'Rank': 2},
  {'Name': 'C', 'Year of Rank':1994, 'Rank': 3}])

dw[dw.Name == 'El Toro'][['Name', 'Year of Rank']]
```

Like this?

Next time you try provide more context like a dummy dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
dw[dw['Name'] == 'El Toro'][['Name','Year of Rank']]
```